# Can a graphics driver cause a memory leak in my application?

Tags: c++, video, memory-leaks, drivers, ms-media-foundation

I have a .NET WPF application that uses a C++/CLI library we wrote to control video via Microsoft Media Foundation libraries.

When monitoring the private bytes performance counter on various devices this counter remains steady over a period of weeks. However on a system with Intel GMA3650 graphics this performance counter increases at a noticeable and steady rate when the application is running (playing video). If I disable Aero by switching to the Windows 7 Basic theme this counter is noticebly better albeit with slight and steady increase stll.

The C++/CLI code is mainly doing basic video transport control functions as well as adding/removing video segments from a sequence. It also takes a snapshot of the current video via `IMFSourceReader::ReadSample`.

It looks like this driver is causing a memory leak in my application but I'm not even sure if that's possible. Are all applications vulnerable to memory leaks in any underlying operating system libraries or libraries used by the OS in execution of the application?

Comment: Yes it can cause memory leaks!

Comment: I might met a similar problem. Our C++ program cause memory leak on windows 7 wiith the Aero mode. But when the mode turn to basic, there's mo memory leak any more. I guess it's a system bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any piece of software which can allocate memory in your processes virtual address space is capable of causing a memory leak.  Drivers can allocate memory in such a way through functions like `ZwOpenSection`.  Hence they can cause a process to leak memory

Now just because it can leak memory doesn't mean it does leak memory.  It's far more likely that there is a bug in your application.  The first step is to profile and figure out what memory is leaking and move on from there

Comment: But I have profiled my application across many devices without a leak (running for weeks), now on this new device with this graphics chip suddenly a massive leak. Our code base is not large and practically all the C++/CLI code is called constantly. How could the same code cause a leak on one device but not another? Our code doesn't test for Aero on/off either so how could disabling change memory use by our code specifically?

Comment: @DaveO perhaps there is an API call which you are forgetting to call a free method on where the Intel driver allocates memory and other drivers don't.  That would have all of the symptoms you are describing.  Note I'm not saying it's definitely a bug in your app, i just believe it's more likely

Comment: As it happens Microsoft Windows Media player also crashes and leaks memory using this driver.